# Removing navigation buttons for SCO package

Tags: xml, scorm, scorm2004

The LMS automatically displays prev, next and close buttons. I can hide these buttons and [here](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/sequencing/sequencing-definition-model/) tells about it. But I didn't find an example of how to do. What is the approach to handle this?

---

*Edit:*

... an other source clearly indicates the pieces to do this job. Adding these bits into manifest file;

```
<sequencing>
<controlMode choice="false" choiceExit="false" flow="true" />
</sequencing>
```

will solve the problem.

---

I posted this as an answer but it did not go well.  It seems `choice` property does it but LMS still show these. The flash content goes back and forward itself well and I just do not want to display buttons. So how can I hide nav buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this on a item after the title.

```
<adlnav:presentation>
     <adlnav:navigationInterface>
        <adlnav:hideLMSUI>continue</adlnav:hideLMSUI>
        <adlnav:hideLMSUI>previous</adlnav:hideLMSUI>
     </adlnav:navigationInterface>
 </adlnav:presentation>
```

Comment: Is there any source I can check for other nav elements' tags? Right now it work as it is but need some extra.

Comment: spec had previous, continue, exit, exitAll, abandon, abandonAll and suspendAll.  This can be located within the SCORM_2004_4ED_v1_1_CAM_20090814.pdf in section 5.2.1.1.1, or via adlnet.org via another SCORM 2004 Edition if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Some LMSs use custom XML markup, too. Might want to check with the LMS vendor.

For example, SumTotal's TotalLMS (now "ELMS") uses additional proprietary markup to indicate whether to show the LMS's built-in nav controls.

http://files.articulate.com/kb/ap09/Working_with_the_API_for_SCORM_Extensions_in_SumTotal.pdf

For SumTotal, add this to your `xmlSchemaLocation` attribute: `http://www.click2learn.com/xsd/c2l_cp_rootv1p1 c2l_cp_rootv1p1.xsd`, add this attribute to your `<manifest>`: `xmlns:c2lcp="http://www.click2learn.com/xsd/c2l_cp_rootv1p1"`, then add this markup to your imsmanifest, just before the `</manifest>`:

```
<c2lcp:ItemDataExtra>
    <c2lcp:ItemData Type="Course">
        <c2lcp:ItemSpecificData>
            <c2lcp:CourseData>
                <c2lcp:PackageProperties>
                    <c2lcp:CourseDisplay>
                        <c2lcp:ShowNavBar>no</c2lcp:ShowNavBar>
                    </c2lcp:CourseDisplay>
                    <c2lcp:Launch>
                        <c2lcp:Width>1280</c2lcp:Width>
                        <c2lcp:Height>1024</c2lcp:Height>
                        <c2lcp:AllowResize>yes</c2lcp:AllowResize>
                    </c2lcp:Launch>
                </c2lcp:PackageProperties>
            </c2lcp:CourseData>
        </c2lcp:ItemSpecificData>
    </c2lcp:ItemData>
</c2lcp:ItemDataExtra>
```

Comment: Great info, always impressed with all the little LMS subtleties.